how to use page routing in blazor without getting a 404 error
I've created a blazor app (.net 8, default weather template) and I want to add my own pages but no matter what I try I get a 404 error each time I try to access my newly added page
In the components folder Ive created a new folder
Components -> Agency
inside here I have a bunch of pages for CRUD operations
Components -> Agency -> Pages -> Create
Components -> Agency -> Pages -> Edit
etc
in Create.cshtml I have the following page directive
@page "Agency/Create"
and a reference to the code behind model
@model App.Web.Components.Agency.Pages.CreateModel
There is some standard html with a h1 and some text (really simple)
In the layout directory there is a NavMenu, Ive added this html
 <div class="nav-item px-3">
 <NavLink class="nav-link" href="Agency/Create">
     <span class="bi bi-list-nested-nav-menu" aria-hidden="true"></span> Agency
 </NavLink>

This is just an addition to the navmenu from the main project, all the other navigation works perfectly well but If I click the "Agency" link I get a 404 error
From what Ive read on Blazor routing, shouldn't the page directive allow me to navigate to this page ?
This has got me stumped, I just cant see any reason why this wont work, can anyone tell me what Im doing wrong ?
Type of Interactivity - Auto
Im basically trying to learn Blazor, create.cshtml was created as part of the razor page scaffolding wizard (along with a few others)
So it created pages, not components (which is fine for the purpose of learning)
All the other pages work fine, there is even an account section (exactly the same folder structure, Account -> Pages) that works perfectly.It makes no sense
many thanks

Type of Interactivity - Server/WebAssembly/Auto?   Interactivity location - Global/Per Page.Component?  Why are you cresting Create.cshtml, not Razor components?  Have you gone through any of the many online tutorials?  Or https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/tutorials/?view=aspnetcore-8.0

To solve this issue I needed to create them as .razor pages, not .cshtml.
